# using the test population as an eval_set when doing hyperparameter optimization

Tags: validation, boosting, hyperparameter

I'm looking at this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-example-of-hyperparameter-optimization-on-xgboost-lightgbm-and-catboost-using-hyperopt-12bc41a271e) for hyperparameters optimization of boosting regressors using `hyperopt`. 
I noticed that for each trial, it uses the following code for the fit:

```py
reg.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train,
        eval_set=[(self.x_train, self.y_train), (self.x_test, self.y_test)], 
        early_stopping_rounds=10)
pred = reg.predict(self.x_test)
loss = para['loss_func'](self.y_test, pred)
```

where the default metric used for validation is `eval_metric='RMSE'`, the same as the default objective used for optimization `objective='reg:squarederror'.

1. is it OK to use y_test for both validation (which is used for early stopping) or is this a recipe for overfitting?
2. why should we use y_train as a validation set as well? isn't it wasteful since the objective always improves on the training set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it OK to use y_test for both validation (which is used for early
> stopping) or is this a recipe for overfitting?

It not a recipe for over-fitting unless the test set is small, but it is a recipe for an optimistically biased performance estimate, so I would strongly advise against it and use something like nested cross-validation, or at least partitioning the data into a training set, a validation set (for optimising the hyper-parameters) and a test set (for performance evaluation).  For an explanation/demonstration of why this is a problem, see the paper I wrote with Mrs Marsupial:

Gavin C. Cawley, Nicola L. C. Talbot, On Over-fitting in Model Selection and Subsequent Selection Bias in Performance Evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 11(70):2079−2107, 2010. ([www](https://jmlr.org/papers/v11/cawley10a.html))

> why should we use y_train as a validation set as well? isn't it
> wasteful since the objective always improves on the training set?

Using cross-validation on the training set to get a model selection criterion for hyper-parameter optimisation is a sensible approach.  For some machine learning methods (e.g. SVM) you can get an estimate (or bound) on the leave-one-out cross-validation error almost for free as a by-product of the training algorithm, which is very handy for efficient hyper-parameter optmisaion.  Just don't use that estimate for performance evaluation as well as hyper-parameter optimisation as it will be optimistically biased.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's ok, but this should actually be called "validation set", an additional set should be used for test that is not used for neither early stopping nor hyper-parameter search.
2. The model uses the last set for early stopping, the training set is there just to see the model performance on it during the training process. Comparing the performance of both sets can provide insight on whether the model is experiencing underfit/overfit and help the modeler in hyper-parameter or model search.